# Correct filtering of Items.Restrict in Outlook.Application on Python

Tags: python, outlook, com

I'm writing a Python script using pywin32 to pull outlook email from a folder by subject to use elsewhere.

I am using the line `emails = target_folder.Items.Restrict(search_criteria)` to filter the email results by Subject.

Rather than the complete subject, I want to filter them based on if they contain a particular word.

I have tried the following, based off of other sources.

```
criteria = "sample"
search_criteria = f"[Subject] = '*{criteria}*'"
```

But it is not working. What is the correct way to filter it properly when the subject contains the desired string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following filter query.

```
target_folder.Items.Restrict("@SQL=(urn:schemas:httpmail:subject LIKE '%sample%')")
```